WPF How to add different UI elements on top of TabControl?
I currently have a TabControl set up for my WPF application in the form:
<TabControl Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="0">
    <TabItem Width="100" Header="Home" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Width="120" Header="Support" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Width="100" Header="Help" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"></TabItem>
</TabControl>

However, I wish to add other UI elements on top of this tab bar such as an expander and a TextBlock which are right aligned. I have tried messing with the dimensions of the TabControl property, but that affects the size of the content displayed on the tab as well.
How can I add elements on top of this tab bar without affecting the content displayed by it?

You would put the TabControl and the other elements together in a common Panel, e.g. a Grid or a DockPanel. See Panels Overview.

Figured this out with a little research as I wasn't getting the exact answer I wanted, leaving it here:
The Panel.ZIndex property can be used to overlay something above the rest, so for this case with the information being required over a TabControl, it would be in the form:
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,10,0" Panel.ZIndex="1">
   <Expander Header="Options" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
   <TextBlock Text="Text" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>

